# If $F$ is an extension field of the field $K$ such that $[F:K] =1$, then $F=K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Suppose $F$ is an extension field of the field $K$ such that $[F:K] =1$. 
How to prove that $F=K$?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: May be you should say $F\cong K$

Answer (score 2):

Two simple proofs:

- $F$ and $K$ are both $F$-subspaces of $K$. Since $F\subseteq K$ and they have the same dimension, they must be equal.
- If $K$ has dimension $1$ as an $F$-subspace, then $K=Fk$ for every $k\ne0$. In particular, with $k=1$, we get $K=F$.

Answer (score 0):

Just note that one would tend not to say $F=K$ but rather $F \cong K$.

To think of why this should be so, as a hint, think of a one dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, say $V$. Then $V$ "looks like" $\mathbb{R}v$. Can you think of an obvious isomorphism of this to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: While it's important to distinguish equality from isomorphism, in this case equality is correct. To say *"$K$ is an extension field of $F$"* means that $K\supseteq F$, and if furthermore $[K:F]=1$ then it actually does follow that $K=F$.